# Signal function error

Tags: c++, c++-cli, signals, posix

I am new to C++, in my main method am facing with an error in signal function.
When i build the application output comes which is error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
 signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you `#include <signal.h>`?

Comment: @Raul andres - yes i did add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already `#include <signal.h>`, the error cause might be your project is compiled with `/clr:pure`. You cannot call `signal()` in a pure CLR project.

You can fix it by changing `/clr:pure` to `/clr`:

1. Open Project property page.
2. Change the setting in: `Configuration Properties` ->  `C/C++` -> `All Options` -> `Common Language RunTime Support`.

Answer (score 0):

The C include file may lack `extern C {` around the declaration.
Since this is C++ you might be better off including `<csignal>` than `<signal.h>`.

```
#include <csignal>
```